# React CORS issue with fetch for POST request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, fetch, cross-origin-read-blocking

I've an api which runs on http://localhost:10080/v1 **[I cannot change the code of api]**.
I've built a react application to send some post data to that api.
React app runs on http://localhost:3000

```
handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    const base_url="http://localhost:10080/v1/"
    const data={<<some json data>>}
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    fetch(base_url,{
        method:'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        header:headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(data),

    })

}
```

When I change `mode` to `cors` I'm getting Cross-Origin Request Blocked.
When I change `mode` to `no-cors`, I'm getting `415-Unsupported Media Type` error because when we disable cors then we cannot change request headers(given in other answers and documentation). How to overcome this and send a post request to that api?

Comment: if you runs it on localhost why cant you change the code of api ? anyway, did you try using cors-anywhere https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

Comment: api is part of an application which I've downloaded so can't change it. Yes I've tried that it didn't work in my case.

Comment: Does it work when you try api with postman?

Comment: @SuleymanSah It works when I access api through Firefox and I'm able to send post request using browser's tools. So, it must be working with postman as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add a proxy in your package.json :

```
   "proxy": "http://localhost:10080"
```

for more info on my research to try to answer you question you can find [this website](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/dealing-with-cors-in-create-react-app)

Comment: Hi, I tried this but didn't work in my case.Thanks.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. I had a similar issue with Angular and also solved it with a proxy. Easy to implement and worked perfect.

Comment: @kotlasaicharanreddy Did you restart your React app? It worked for me using fetch, notice that you need to use relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code to bind RadTreeView and ContextMenu dynamically with edit, delete and add features.

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnClientContextMenuItemClicking(sender, args)
     {
        var menuItem = args.get_menuItem();
        var treeNode = args.get_node();
        menuItem.get_menu().hide();
        switch (menuItem.get_value())
         {
            case "edit":
                treeNode.startEdit();
                break;
         }
     }
</script>
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

Run "npm install cors" in your Node application using CMD and then add the following code in index.js file of your node application.

```js
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cors = require('cors');
var request = require('request-promise');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen('YOUR PORT', function(){console.log('Listening port 3000')});
app.use(cors());
app.get('/exchangeInfo', function (req,res) {
    request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'YOUR API',
        resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    }).then(r => {
        res.send(JSON.parse(r.body));
    }).catch()
});
```

You can use the above code in you local to run local server and overcome cors or you can use chrome plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-orign-cors-changer/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc?hl=en-GB

Comment: I'm sending a POST request not GET request.

Comment: Just change the request to POST and send the params in api @kotlasaicharanreddy. Ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R98rmaRkgy8

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming "http://localhost:10080/v1/" is your backend API if it's an express app ensure you have cors installed.

Comment: Hi, yes its backend but not sure on which it is built as it's just an application which I downloaded. So no idea of backend and can't change anything in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess but in my opinion the issue can not be solved without changing your local API.

Your local api runs on localhost:10080 and does not allow CORS, so it will block everything not coming from localhost:10080.

From there, the two options are either your local API allows for some options and to allow CORS, or there is a way to serve your frontend from your API (and thus having the same origin).

See this ressource about CORS server-side: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control

Comment: Hi,I don't have access to change api as it is bundled with an application which I downloaded and cannot change.